# How works anchorPoint - UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I wanna make a rotation around a point but NOT a point into my UIImageView.
I found solution with `imageView.layer.anchorPoint` but when i change it, the position of my `imageView` change too. I understand why but I can't put my imageView on a definitive position and change the anchorPoint to a definitive position.

I hope I explained my problem well...

Regards,
KL94

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way is to house your UIImageView in another UIView that is centered at the desired rotation point. Then, just rotate that UIView.

http://mohrt.blogspot.com/2009/05/rotating-view-around-arbitrary-point.html